# Sverchok // "Progressive" animation, animate through a given period of frames

Tags: animation, animation-nodes, timeline, sverchok

I've been using sverchok since a few weeks. Love it.

**Is there a dedicated way to animate things in Sverchok on a "progressive" basis ?**

I have an example : **let’s say I want to count from 1 to 10 on a 30 frames long basis** (based on a Bool "True" outputed by a switch node, but anyway). I'm thinking, as a first guess, of using the curves & eases parameters of the Mix Number Node for examples. Maybe the Timer node could be usefull too.

**Is there a well-known method to do this ?**

Or do I have to create it "diy" (I was thinking to use a Loop for a given period of frames before switching back the switch node to False, but I never used such node)

Hoping someone can help me

Be safe :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create simple animate number group node like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. That's pretty simple and effective, indeed. It was also pretty easy to implement in my current project, thanks again.
I have a last issue on this, maybe you can help me : this little group of node should only be triggered once a particular event occurs, which trigger a switch to "True". Let say I want to increment for 25 frames, is there a way to make a switch node "stick" to its True position for those 25 frames ? I guess that another way to achieve this would be to trigger a 25 frames counter when the switch node hits it True position.
I'll comeback here if I find smth.